# IIS - Missing Windows Authentication Feature

Tags: iis, windows-8, windows-authentication, iis-8

There's anyway to install/enable IIS Windows Authentication when it's missing in "Turn Windows Features On or Off" menu?

I'm running an Win8 machine in a Local Workgroup.

Comment: Flagged for migration to superuser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you need [Pro or Enterprise edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8_editions)

Comment: Has somebody been able to make sure of this?

Comment: Has anyone been able to confirm this??

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, so far tried these, you should also take a look at these settings

- check the module if you have WindowsAuthentication managed module
- enable appcmd set config /section:windowsAuthentication /enabled:true
- enable it in the app's web.config

`

```
<security>
  <authentication>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true"></windowsAuthentication>
  </authentication>
</security>
```

`

I've tried these on my Windows 8 desktop which is not part of the domain, but it doesn't work, the response header is just 401 without any www auth headers. I wonder what will happen in your case when the machine is part of the domain.