# IIS authentication error

Tags: iis, localhost

I'm trying to simply run a local website which has sime basic HTML files using IIS.
Through the IIS Manager I have created a new website and have set the physical path to the directory with the HTML files.
However when I input the physical path I get the following warning:

> The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a
>   built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS
>   Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make
>   sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the
>   physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the
>   application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify
>   that \$ has Read access to the physical path.
>   Then test these settings again.

Now, when I navigate to the site through localhost I get the following Unauthorized error:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page because of
>   the access control list (ACL) configuration or encryption settings for
>   this resource on the Web server.

What's going on here? When I right click my folder I seem to have given access to everyone. I haven't made any specific IIS changes so what could be the issue here?

EDIT:
MAN I cannot believe this. My case is so simple (I just wanna display some HTML files on localhost) which should require ZERO configuration at all. Yet IIS fails to meet the demand.

EDIT: I think everyone should have permission to my folder. Here's a picture of the permissions screen for the folder:
[image]

Comment: Did you reset app pool/IIS after giving read access on folder to everyone?

Comment: @PankajKapare I haven't changed my folder settings because it seems that everyone has access. I have added a picture of my folder permissions screen in my question. It should give everyone access right?

Comment: It would for a file share, yes. But this being a server issue, you'll also need to configure IIS for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with a set of server protocols is different than adding files to a share. In this case, you're going to want to open IIS and navigate to the website you added it as.

There, you'll see a variety of icons, some under the heading of ASP.NET, some under IIS. The first heading you'll see under IIS is Authentication. That's the one you want. If this is strictly internal/for learning, go ahead and enable Anonymous Authentication. It's not safe, but it'll get you in the right place to start googling around.

Comment: Anonymous authentication is already enabled.
I haven't done any changes at all (everything should be default).

Comment: Hm. Is Windows Authentication enabled?

Comment: How do I enable that? I only see Anonymous authentication and ASP.NET impersonation? BTW I'm running IIS 8 on Windows 8.1
Also, in features I don't see the Windows Authentication checkbox neither.

Comment: Well, to get those other you'll have to Add Or Remove Windows Features. Let me look at IIS eight and see what the deal is.

Comment: What does your web.config look like? Could you post that?

Comment: It seems that Windows Authentication is only available in Pro or Enterprise - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12691197/iis-missing-windows-authentication-feature?answertab=oldest#tab-top. Then again, all I wanna do is to display a couple of html pages, I shouldnt need pro or enterprise for that.

Comment: Yeah, I only run Pro/server, so I'd forgotten. Look at your Authentication page, then right-click on Anonymous Authentication>Edit. It should show either a specific user, or application pool identity. Try setting it to a user who has explicit access.

Comment: Whoa that did the trick. Wow I cannot believe how moronic this security can be at times. Anyways, thanks a lot for helping me out!